# Starting a process and killing it from Ruby on Rails app without leaving zombie process

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, zombie-process

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application. Part of the functionality is starting and closing connection with Modbus slave via serial port, getting data and storing it into database. Also I made a script in python that does exactly what I need so I don't want to reinvent the wheel and rewrite it into Ruby.

My idea is to start a process which will execute python script and kill the process whenever it is not needed anymore.

I start the process as follows, so I can access it's pid:

```
def start
    ...
    @@pids[ object.id ] = IO.popen("python ./python_script_name.py").pid
    ...
```

@@pids is a hash which stores all started processes' pids with key as object.id (presumption is that each object can start only one process)

When I want to close the connection I kill the process like:

```
def stop
    ...
    pid = @@pids[ object.id ]
    system("kill #{pid}")
```

This results in zombie process (visible after `ps aux | grep python`):

```
[python] <defunct>
```

I tried to send `SIGCHLD` signal to rails application (as it is parent of earlier called python script) but it doesn't work.

I want to add that I might need to call/kill this process quite often so it can result in huge amount of zombie processes.

How can I kill a process without leaving zombie process behind?

Comment: your python script reacts badly to TERM. try to send it KILL?

Comment: I've tried both `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM` - same result.

Comment: provide some reproducible example as it "works for me as expected" with minimal python script w/ sys.stdin.readline() inside.

Comment: Script is also using 2 modules written by me, it's too many lines of code to post in here. But probably you turned me into right direction - I will focus on script instead. Will post the result when I have it.

Comment: Have you verified that @@pids is giving you back the correct pid (why I always opt for `Hash#fetch` over `Hash#[]`? It seems like it could be easy enough for that object to get messed with, especially given Rails dev reloading (object ids could change). Have you tried creating some other process that you control and can see, to see whether it receives the signal? (ie trap it and write it to a file, then pass it to the original handler).

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Yes, I verified it using byebug gem. I could not kill the script without it anyways (the script is killed, the problem is zombie process left behind). 
also @iced Regarding catching the signal: I implemented `signal` module in python script for both `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM`. They are working (signal is caught properly) but zombie process is still left behind. I used `sys.exit()`, `sys.quit()`, even `raise SystemExit` - all with same result. Maybe there is some other way to terminate script and telling parent process (rails server in this case) that it is terminated properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not in the python script - signals are handled properly by default (no change after implementing `signal` module).

The issue is in the ruby script. After killing a process, its parent (rails server in this case) needs to know somehow that it was killed. For this purpose there is a `wait` function. From ruby documentation:

> The parent process should use Process.wait to collect the termination status of its child

So to correctly handle killing a child process one need to follow:

```
def stop
    ...
    pid = @@pids[ object.id ]
    Process.kill( 15, pid )
    Process.wait( pid )
    ...
```